# python name not defined

Tags: python, function

this is  my hangman program. it returns a "NameError: name 'a' is not defined." please help me in fixing this. thank you very much.

```
import random

invalid= [" ","'",".",",","'", '"', "/", "\ ", '"',";","[","]", "=", "-", "~", "`", "§","±","!","@","#","$","%","^","&","*","(",")","_","+","{","}","|",":","?",">","<","0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
choice = 0

print("Welcome to HANGMAN!")

def Menu():
    print("[1] Play Hangman")
    print("[2] Instructions ")
    print("[3] Highscores")
    print("[4] Exit")

    choice = int(input("Please choose from the Menu: "))
    if(not(choice <=4)):
        print("Choose again.")
        return Menu()
    return choice

while True:
    choice = Menu()
    if choice == 1:
        print("Categories: ")

        print("[1] Movies")
        print("[2] Animals")
        print("[3] Something Blue")
        choice_category = int(input("Please Choose a Category: "))

        print("-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-")

        print("Difficulties:")

        print("[1] Easy")
        print("[2] Average")
        print("[3] Difficult")
        choice_difficulty = int(input("Please Choose a Difficulty: "))

        superword = a(choice_category, choice_difficulty)
        legitgame(superword)

    elif choice == 2:
        print("Let yourself be hanged by mistaking the letters.")

    elif choice == 3:
        readHandle = open("Scores.txt","r")
        names = []
        for line in readHandle:
            name = line[:-1]
            names.append(name)
        readHandle.close()
        print()
        Menu()
    elif choice == 4:
        print("Thank you for playing.")
        Menu()


hangman =["                         =========="
             "      |        |"
             "      O        |"
             "               |"
             "               |"
             "           | ", 

            "       =========="
            "       |        |"
            "       O        |"
            "       |        |"
            "            |"
            "            | ", 

            "      ==========   "       
            "      |        |"
            "      O        |"
            "     /|        |"
            "               |"
            "           | ", 

            "      =========="
            "      |        |"
            "      O        |"
            "     /|\       |"
            "           |"
            "           | ",

            "      =========="
            "      |        |"
            "      O        |"
            "     /|\       |"
            "     /     |"
            "           | ", 

            "      =========="
            "      |        |"
            "      O        |"
            "     /|\       |"
            "     / \       |"
            "           |  "]
```

#definition function for different options in a specific category and     difficulty
    def a(choice_category, choice_difficulties):

```
    if choice_category == 1:
        readHandle = open("movies.txt", 'r')
        lines = readHandle.readlines()
    elif choice_category == 2:
        readHandle = open("animals.txt", 'r')
        lines = readHandle.readlines()
    elif choice_category == 3:
        readHandle = open("something blue.txt", 'r')
        lines = readHandle.readlines()
    else:
        print("Please choose again.")


    if choice_difficulty == 1:
        word = (lines[0])
    elif choice_difficulty == 2:
        word = (lines[1])
    elif choice_difficulty == 3:
        word = (lines[2])
    else:
        print("Please enter valid characters.")





    legitword = word[:-1].split(".")
    return (random.choice(legitword))


def legitgame (meh):

    length = "__" * len(meh)
    characters = []
    mistake = 0

    while mistake < 6 and length != meh:
        print(hangman[mistake])
        print(length)
        print("Number of wrong guesses: ", mistake)

        guess = (input("Guess:")).upper()


        while len(guess) != 1:
            print("You have inputted multiple letters. Please input a single letter.")
            guess = input("Guess: ").upper()

        while guess in invalid:
            print("You have inputted an invalid character. Please try again.")
            guess = input ("Guess: ").upper()

        while guess in characters:
            print("You have already inputted this letter. Please try again.")
            guess= input("Guess: ").upper()


        if guess in meh:
            print()
            print("Fantastic! You have entered a correct letter.")
            characters.append(guess)
            correct = ""

            for x in range (0,len(meh)):
                if guess == meh[x]:
                    correct += guess
                else:
                    correct += length[x]
            length = correct

        else:
            character.append(guess)
            print("Sorry. You have inputted an incorrect letter. Please try again.")
            mistake += 1

        if mistake >= 6:
            print(hangman[6])
            print("The correct word is: ", meh)
            print("Sorry. You killed the guy. Your conscience is chasing you.")
            print("Game over")

        elif correct == meh:
            print("Congratulations! You saved the puny man.")
            print("You have guessed ", word, "correctly!")
            win()
        Menu()

def win():
    readHandle = open("Scores.txt", "a")
    name = input("Enter your name: ")
    readHandle.write(name + "\n")
    readHandle.close

menu()
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? What is the exact traceback for your error? And your code needs more context, showing us where `legitgame()` is defined. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What is the question of HOMEWORK?

Comment: i'm sorry for the incompleteness. it is a part of my hangman code. it is also the source of the NameError: name 'a' is not defined. please help me in fixing this. thank you.

Comment: i have already posted the complete program

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell for sure with the entire code, but from the given code I assume the error is that you call `a(choice_category, choice_difficulty)` before you have defined it. Put the `def a(...` before `superword = a(choice_category, choice_difficulty)`, and you should be good to go (if this is indeed the problem)

Answer (score 0):

"a" is apparently a function in your program as you have :

```
def a(choice_category, choice_difficulty)
```

This line defines 'a' as a function that requires 2 arguments (choice_category and choice_difficulty)

You need to define the function before you can use it

You program is calling/using the function with this line

```
superword = a(choice_category, choice_difficulty)
```